# Using selenium to download a file via window.open

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a webpage where clicking a link results in a new window popping open that immediately downloads a csv. I haven't been able to figure out the format of the url since it's fairly dense javascript (and one function is called via the `onClick` property while another is called as part of the `href` property. I have not worked with Selenium before, so I was hoping to confirm before getting started that what I want to do is possible. I had read somewhere that downloading files via new popup windows is not necessarily something I can do with Selenium.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. A `this is possible` would be very helpful as would as `here's how you'd do it` even sketched in broad detail. Thanks much!

To be clear, my difficulties primarily stem from the fact that I can't figure out how the URL to download the file is generated. Even looking at the Google chrome network calls, I am not seeing where it is, and it would probably take me many hours to track this down, so I am looking for a solution that relies on clicking specific text in the browser rather than disentangling the cumbersome machinery behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I download files using `Firefox` webdriver. It's essentially creating a browser profile so that the default download location for certain file types are set. You can then verify if the file exists at that location.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# add the file_formats to download
file_formats = ','.join(["text/plain",
                         "application/pdf",
                         "application/x-pdf",
                         "application/force-download"])

preferences = {
    "browser.download.folderList": 2,
    "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": False,
    "browser.download.dir": os.getcwd(),  # will download to current directory
    "browser.download.alertOnEXEOpen": False,
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": file_formats,
    "browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting": False,
    "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force": False,
    "browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete": False,
    "browser.download.manager.useWindow": False,
    "services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": False,
    "pdfjs.disabled": True
}

for pref, val in preferences.items():
    browser_profile.set_preference(pref, val)

browser_binary = webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.FirefoxBinary()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=browser_binary,
                            firefox_profile=browser_profile)

# set the file name that will be saved as when you download is complete
file_name = 'ABC.txt'

# goto the link to download the file from it will be automatically
# downloaded to the current directory
file_url = 'http://yourfiledownloadurl.com'
browser.get(file_url)

# verify if the expected file name exists in the current directory
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
assert os.path.isfile(path)
```

Comment: Thank you Kiran. This is really generous for you to share the code. I realize I was not clear from my post that it's very difficult for me to find out the URL from which the file is being downloaded, that is part of what is presenting my difficulties. Is it possible to modify your code to select the text on which I want to 'click' to download the file?

Comment: @helloB You can replace `browser.get` with `browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()` and it will still download it to the default directory.

Comment: @helloB did my answer help? If not, tell me what failed so I can improve my answer.